# Making Input[number] field dependent for another input[number] field by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every `input` field should be dependent for Total Quiz Marks(`input` field). I just want to set an `attribute: max` which should be `less than or equal to` total quiz marks.
I'm attaching a snapshot & I'm sure it will be clear.
[image]

& I'm also attaching my html code:

```
<form action="../controllers/classroom.php" method="POST">      
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totalMark" name="totalMark" placeholder="Enter quiz mark" required>
    <div class="row">
    <?php
        $count=0;
        $query4="SELECT * FROM enrollments WHERE classId='{$classId}'";
        $res4=mysqli_query($connection, $query4);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res4)){
            $count++;
    ?>
            <div class="col-md-2">#<?php echo $count; ?></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"><?php echo ucwords(getUser($row['userId'])['name']); ?></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><input type="number" class="form-control" name="user[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" placeholder="Enter marks" required>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="quiz-marks" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to make a live validation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easist way is to listen for the `change` event on the `#totalMark` input then change the `max` property. I've used jQuery for brevity, but I'm sure you could use vanilla javascript if you wanted.

```js
$(function(){
 $('#totalMark').change(function(){
  $('.form-control:not(#totalMark)').prop('max',this.value)
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totalMark" name="totalMark" value="20" placeholder="Enter quiz mark" required>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" max="20" required>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" max="20" required>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" max="20" required>
</form>
```